# Connecting to MySQL & MS-SQL yields "Access denied for user" error message

Tags: mysql, sql-server, windows-server-2012, connection

I am trying to connect to both of my database servers, however when using some interfaces (web and some apps), I get the error message:

```
Connection cannot be established with database. Authentication to host 'mysql.<domain name>' for user '<username>' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user '<username>'@'<vps domain name>' (using password: YES)
```

The funny thing is that MySQL Workbench and Microsoft SQL Server Management studio from my local desktop work nicely. When I try to connect from VevoCart or a couple of other web applications, I get that error message.

If I specify the IP address and not the URL (MySQL. or mssql.), then I can connect fine.

I did open the appropriate ports on the Windows firewall, so that is not the issue. Again, if I connect using the IP, then everything works.

Server: Plesk running on Microsoft Windows Server 2012.
Database: MySQL comes bundled with Plesk, but Microsoft SQL Server 2012 was a separate installation.

I thought the issue might be how the subdomain was defined, but that is not the case. The old web hosting company used an A-record, whereas the new company had the MySQL. as a CNAME. I changed that to the IP and still the same problem.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I needed to add an entry to the Windows hosts file for the two database entries. An entry in the DNS is not enough and inside the IP address went to something different, for whatever reason.